# how to filter records by week mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, datatable

I need to filter records by level and by week, that is, if I have 100 records, I only have to show the records of the last 7 days, for example, 30 records for the UTILS level.

```
select tbe.level, COUNT(tbe.level) as contador from tableexample as tbe 
where level = 'UTILS' and week(tbe.date)
```

That is my query but it only brings me the number of records and the level, I would like it if I could filter by the last 7 days, I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand that you correctly that you want to show all columns of "tableexample" filtered to show the last seven days and where level = 'UTILS'?

If yes, you can try this code snippet:

```
select * from tableexample tbe 
where level = 'UTILS' and tbe.date <= dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
```

getdate() retrieves the current date and dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) computes last week's date.